# VS 2019 Windows Form not coming up?

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed VS 2019 and I went to work on a test project to make sure everything is working and I have come across an issue. I made a windows form, when I load it up, it only shows the code. It does not show the designer even though I click on show designer, it just brings me back to the code, no designer form appears. Clicking on Show Code brings up a new instance of that .cs file. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score -1):

Go to your form code and press the keys <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>